# If $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f^\prime(x)=\infty$ then $f^{'}_{+}(x_0)$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus

Assume $f:[x_0,x_0+\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function which is differentiable in $(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$. Assume that $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f^\prime(x)=\infty$. Does it imply that $f^{'}_{+}(x_0)$ does not exist?

I know that in general the derivative need not behave well. I have as an example the derivative of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which does not have a limit at $x_0=0$, yet the function is differentiable at $x_0=0$ (if forced to be continuous at $x_0$). This example, though, has a bounded derivative. I was wondering if relieving this requirement forces $f$ to not be differentiable.

Comment: doesn't your hypotheses imply that also $f'_+(x_0)$ is $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $x > x_0$. From MVT $f(x)-f(x_0)=(x-x_0)f’(c_x)$ where $x_0 < c_x < x$.

Thus, as $x$ goes to $x_0$, $f’(c_x)$ goes to $+\infty$...